# toUpperCase() is not making the string upper case

Tags: javascript

I don't know what I'm doing wrong;
But somehow `.toUpperCase()` String-function is not working on my browser
or do I get something wrong?

```
var string ="kjsdgfiIJHBVSFIU";
string.toUpperCase();
console.log(string);
```

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/axorer/3/edit)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: And in case you find yourself with code that applies toUpperCase to something of type number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208776/jquery-for-in-touppercase-is-not-a-function

Comment: Related: [Filtering Array of Objects Returns Empty Array](/q/68480556/4642212).

Answer (score 29):

`.toUpperCase` returns the upper-cased string.  It is not an in-place modifier method.

```
string = string.toUpperCase();
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Comment: Thanks. It helped me today. I was trying this : typeof('a').toUpperCase() and toUpperCase was not working. I tried wrapping the inital result with String(...).toUpperCase() and it worked. Strings are immutable. Thanks!

Comment: Hello. sorry this is 12 years later comment. How can one know when is or not a in-place modifier method? Is there any way to know it?

Comment: @Germán unfortunately, there's no way to know this. You just have to look up the documentation on that method to experiment with it, or test it out. Most JavaScript core methods don't modify in-place, but there are a few like `Array.sort` that do.

Comment: Well... That makes programming a bit more confusing and time-consuming. I wonder why isn't there a standardisation about these kind of things.

Answer (score 8):

> String is Immutable. Once created, a string object can not be
> modified.

*So here `toUpperCase` returns a new string, This should work-*

```
var string ="kjsdgfiIJHBVSFIU";
var newString = string.toUpperCase();
alert(newString);
```

Answer (score 3):

`toUpperCase` returns the new string, so you must write:

```
string = string.toUpperCase();
```

In many languages, strings are immutable, meaning that they can not be modified once created. While this costs in efficiency, it is important for object oriented programming, because if a String passed by reference to a function was modifiable, the state of objects could be changed without the object's consent.

Answer (score 1):

```
var upperCase = string.toUpperCase();
console.log(upperCase);
```

toUpperCase doesn't transform existing string, it just returns a uppercase string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string ="kjsdgfiIJHBVSFIU";
string = string.toUpperCase();
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Couple you please provide further information and explanation of this to help the question asker? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers about Strings being immutable are great! Here is just another potential run-time reason for getting this error which might be hard to spot at first. It does not detract from any of the above valid answers:

If the object on which the `.toUpperCase()` method is invoked is not a String, then the runtime doesn't 'find' the method `toUpperCase()` since that method/function only exists on String objects.

e.g. `console.log(variableName.toUpperCase());`

If variableName is of the type String, it works fine. If it is of another type (that does not have a `toUpperCase()` method, it says 'toUpperCase() is not a function (since it isn't).

If you know it should be a string, you can cast it like this:

```
console.log(String(variableName).toUppercase());
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know that string is unchangeable unless your reassign it with new name

```
console.log(i, 'is a ' + typeof i);
var N = i.toUpperCase();
console.log(N);
```

Comment: that's not right as you can see in the other answers.

Comment: Well. to think of it as per the documentation, he missed to reassign the variable value. That means that even if he used the toUpperCase, it does not alter the original value stored to the string variable.

Answer (score 1):

- You missed to hold the updated data in `string` key
- It's not a good convention to have name like `string` can be `upperCaseString` or `newString`
  or `updatedString`. That might be for testing purpose but try to follow good 
  convention :) It Will help in future.

```
var string ="kjsdgfiIJHBVSFIU";
string = string.toUpperCase();
console.log(string);

// Output:
KJSDGFIIJHBVSFIU
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `string` value to `toUpperCase` And `toLowercase` then object with method().

```
var string ="kjsdgfiIJHBVSFIU";

console.log(string.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: How does this address the issue from question?