# jQuery for...in toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: jquery

With typical input as below...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="actEmail" data-value="1"/>Department one</li>
```

in my function...

```
var chksDept = $('input[type=checkbox].actEmail:checked');
var depts = Array();

chksDept.each(function() { 
    depts.push($(this).data('value').toUpperCase());  
});
```

Why I got the error :

> `$(...).data(...).toUpperCase()` is not a function?

What I need is to grab all data value in uppercase.

Comment: A number to uppercase?

Comment: Have you checked the response from `$(this).data('value')` before proceeding any further?

Comment: I got the data and there is no error when I remove .toUpperCase().

Comment: In `.data('value')` the value is the key and first you need to define the value of it. and then access that by the key of that. then you can  use .toUpperCase(). see http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value returned from `this $(this).data('value')` is of the type `number`. I.e:

```
console.log(typeof $(this).data('value'));
```

You first need to check to see if it is a `number`, and convert it to a `string` first. Like so:

```
var chksDept = $('input[type=checkbox].actEmail:checked');
var depts = Array();

chksDept.each(function() { 
    var data = $(this).data('value');
    if (typeof data === 'number') {
         data = ""+data;   
    }
    depts.push(data.toUpperCase());  
});

console.log(depts);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `data` method for `data-value='1'` attribute returns a number and Number object doesn't have `toUpperCase` method, assuming that your `data-*` attributes contain both numeric and non-numeric values and you want to convert the non-numeric values to uppercase, you can use `attr` method instead that returns a string.

```
$(this).attr('data-value').toUpperCase();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B8FRE/

This happens as `data-*` attributes are mapped to the `dataset` property of the elements and there is a difference between properties and attributes of an element.