# Need to change text to upper case in JavaScript - createJs

Tags: javascript, uppercase, createjs

I'm new to JavaScript and I have an HTML page with JavaScript where I need to show the text in a field with text "test text tuu" to upper case. I have tried to change it so:

```
this.harmonicField = new cjs.Text("test text tuu", "24px 'Fort Medium'", "#FFFFFF").toUpperCase();
```

and also like this:

```
this.harmonicField = this.harmonicField.toUpperCase();
```

but none of the commands work. When use these commands I don't see there anything - no text. Without the command toUpperCase()it works.

I have post it on pastebin.com (JavaScript and HTML):

- https://pastebin.com/ybs8y4EB
- https://pastebin.com/BuwBRVuA

How do I change the input text to upper case?

Comment: `toUpperCase` is exactly the right way to do it. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: welcome and please check [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [avoid asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: When I have added it to the script then the text disapear, and then is there nothing.

Comment: What is `cjs.Text`? You probably need to upper case its value, not try to uppercase that object itself.

Comment: you need to do something like this: `this.harmonicField.getStringValue().toUpperCase()` as harmonicField is propaply not an instance of String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer clearly.
`toUpperCase` is only applied to the `String` it cannot be applied directly to an `Object` as you trying to do.
try something like this (i'm assuming you're using createJs library):

```
var text = "test text tuu".toUpperCase();
this.harmonicField = new createjs.Text(text, "24px 'Fort Medium'", "#FFFFFF");
```

So you don't apply `toUpperCase` to the object but to a string.
Also using `this` is always confusing but i think this could work:
`this.harmonicField.text = String(this.harmonicField.text).toUpperCase();`

In your case this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326582/touppercase-is-not-making-the-string-upper-case) from 2013 offers many good pointers in my opnion!